# Hair particle options greyed out after cromping

Tags: particles

Can I really not change the emission number and source ect of the particle system after I cromped the hair?

I am in object mode but the options are grey. So I have to delete edit and cromp again?
[image]

Comment: Yes, you have to.

Comment: Ok just wanted to make sure so it's not like I can bake it or something.

Comment: The problem (I think) is that if you increase the number of the hairs, the new ones don't have information about the editing.